# Catching an error with put object and s3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-4

I'm using S3 php sdk and the larval implementation of this to put an object on to S3.

```
try {
    $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket', 
    'Key' =>  'abc',
    'Body' => $img->encode(null, 90),
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => $img->mime()
));

}
catch (S3Exception $e) {

    var_dump('error');
    die();
}
```

But the above code does not seem to catch errors. I set an incorrect bucket and I still get the error:

```
type:Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchBucketException, message:The specified bucket does not exist,…
```

How can I catch this error and act on it accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Use the right parent class

To catch all S3 exceptions - make sure to refer to the right namespace:

```
catch (\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
```

Or

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

...

catch (S3Exception $e) {
```

Otherwise, the catch block will *not* capture exceptions thrown by the S3 library.

Comment: Ah nevermind, the image was undefined. Perfect answer, thanks. Will accept asap.